# Atlassian Git API Diff Commits using Git notation

Tags: bitbucket-server

I have successfully been able to "diff" two files using the stash git API, however, each time you have to specify the full hashes of the commits, like so:

```
rest/api/latest/projects/{project}/diff/{path to file}?since={hash}&until={hash}
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
rest/api/latest/projects/{project}/diff/{path to file}?since=HEAD^^&until=HEAD
```

To resemble:

`git diff HEAD^^ HEAD {my_file}` (So diff between the HEAD and previous commits on that file.)

The only way I have been able to get a list of historical commits from the API is using the following from their docs:

```
https://stash.atlassian.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/JIRA/repos/jira/commits
```

which will: "the latest commits to the jira repository in the JIRA project" but not for a specific file.

From what I have been able to find it seems as though the API does not support this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this, thanks to my Firfox console. The UI makes use of a history drop down showing the last 25 commits to the file with the following URL:

```
rest/api/latest/projects/{project}/commits?path={path_to_fil‌​e}&until=refs%2Fhead‌​s%2Fmaster&start=0&l‌​imit=25
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer (by clicking on the tick mark). This shows the question as completed.